# Link rotating images in existing javascript

Tags: javascript

its been a while since I've dug my heals into JS and could use some help. Looking to modify this existing script to include a link for each rotating image... want to link the object called "text" to the same URL for each image. any ideas?

```
//cur_index = 1;
cur_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
//var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
num_image = 5;
//alert(cur_index);
interval  = 300000; // 5min between rotations
function rotate(){
   // if(cur_index > num_image)
   //    cur_index = 1;
        if(cur_index == 0)
       cur_index = 1;
    var imag,text;
    if(document.getElementById){
        imag = document.getElementById("faceImage");
        text = document.getElementById("faceText");
    }else if(document.all) {        
        imag = document.all["faceImage"];
        text = document.all["faceText"];
    }else if(document.layers){
        imag = document.layers["faceImage"];
        text = document.layers["faceText"];
    }

    var imageUrl = "/path/face" + cur_index + ".jpg";
    var textUrl = "/path/face" + cur_index + "_text.gif";
    imag.src = imageUrl;
    text.src = textUrl;
    //cur_index++;
    cur_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    setTimeout('rotate()',interval);
}
```

Comment: so, to be clear, I am looking to add an href to the text object.

Comment: Hard to see what you are tyring to do without respective markup & css. Possible for you to create a jsFiddle or a codepen please? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. while I work on a jsFiddle let me try to explain again. so this script rotates through a set of images (2 per instance). a GIF and a JPG. when loaded onto the page, the images rotate but none of them link. 
So I want to add a hyperlink to the the object called text. I tried text.href to no avail.. does this help?

Comment: kind-of :) but I still wish to see the markup ;)